# Prometheus deletes metrics once the target is down

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have written a small application to expose metrics to prometheus. In prometheus, I have configured this target. But, once I stop the application, the metrics are no longer visible in prometheus. I expect the metrics to be retained. Please help me on how enable the same. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

From your description I believe you're looking at the "current" results, which, if Prometheus can't access the endpoint will not display anything other than the "up" metric which will show it's down.

You would need to switch to the graph view and select a relevant time period which will display the metrics it has collected. E.g. if your application went down within the last hour, then you could set the graph view for the past two hours

https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/browser/